# java equivalent of [cA,cH,cV,cD] = dwt2(X,'wname') in matlab

Tags: java, matlab, image-processing, wavelet-transform

How can I do same thing in java as does [cA,cH,cV,cD] = dwt2(X,'wname') in matlab ?

More specifically I need wavelet transform coefficients for "Daubechies 2" wavelet of an Image or 2D array of numeric values. This can be done very easily in matlab in single line just by [cA,cH,cV,cD] = dwt2(X,'db2'). But I need it too be done in java.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I have been trying jwave but couldn't figure out how to get the four coefficients (cA,cH,cV,cD ) with jwave.

Comment: Hi, did you get something?? let me know if so.. I too need convert long matlab code to java

Comment: No, not yet. I need this to implement my undergrad thesis research. While doing thesis, i used matlab script to do wavelet transform. Now we are implementing my thesis research as a web service using java. May be we will need to implement this wavelet transform in java.